# Get 10 values from google sheets to my mit app inventor App

Tags: google-sheets, app-inventor

I'm currently developping an App in MIT App inventor that reads the last row of a google sheet.
The problem is when the number of the columns exceeds 6, I can't get the other values, I only get the 6 values, but when there is less or equal 6 numbers, the result id good.

When I tried to see the .csv file, the result is there is no more than 6 values.

[image: The MIT app inventor]
[image: The google sheets table]
[image: The downloaded csv file]

What I need to do to make it works?

Comment: you might want to ask in the [MIT App Inventor community](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/)... there you also can find TimAI2, who is specialized in Google Sheets questions for App Inventor...

Comment: Thank you Taifun